# Flask app secret key is not loading with Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, secret-key

When I try to run my Flask using `gunicorn -w 3 wsgi:app`, and visit the page via the ip address, then I receive the following error: `RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF.` in the terminal.

I am not sure what is causing this issue because: I have set a secret key in `.env` and I have confirmation that it is being loaded by Flask because when I run the app using `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`, then the code`print(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])` prints the secret key to the terminal. 
I imagine this is something to do with Gunicorn needing a different code for it to load the secret key.

My Flask app is structured like so:

```
-denise
--configmodule.py
--__init__.py
--site.db
--models.py
--main
--static
--template
-migrations
-venv
-wsgi.py
-.env
```

I don't have much experience setting up servers, here are the code from the relevant files:

`__init__.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from denise.configmodule import Config
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
mail = Mail()
csrf = CSRFProtect()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app,db)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    print('SECRET_KEY')
    print(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    print('SECRET_KEY')

    #with app.app_context()
    from .main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(main)
    return app
```

configmodule.py file:

```py
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))

class Config(object):
    DEBUG=True
    SECRET_KEY=environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///site.db'
    ENV='development'
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = environ.get('EMAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER')
    MAIL_MAX_EMAILS = 5
    RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC')
    RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE')
```

Wsgi.py file:

```py
from denise import create_app
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

.env file:

```py
SECRET_KEY='hiiii17011b97b7ed4aeb9ae7f75a0b66a006c8efd4ab0759e5d2'
EMAIL_USER='email@email.email'
EMAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER='email@email.email'
EMAIL_PASS='password'
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC='randomstringofletter'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE='lalalalalal'
```

I have tried a few tutorials on deploying Flask apps to production by Corey Schafer and Pretty Printed. I guess I have missed something somewhere.

Comment: How do you run Gunicorn?

Comment: With `gunicorn -w 3 wsgi:app`

Comment: So, your top-level project directory has files `.env` and `wsgi.py`, and subdirectories `denise/`, `migrations/` and `venv/`? Are you sure there is no `.env` file in the `denise/` subdirectory as well?

Comment: Aside from that, it is a stackoverflow rule that you should include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Your code is not the shortest possible. I suggest to copy the directory and start removing things until you reach the bare minimum. While doing that, it is likely you will discover the solution yourself.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides I am absolutely certain that there isn't another `.env` file. There is a `configmodule.py`, which loads a few variables from the `.env` file.

Comment: I'm curious, you mention using `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` works, but could it be that the env varibale is set already regardles of your loading function? What happens if you run `printenv | grep SECRET`? Does that print anything?

Answer (score 3):

Good old spamming of print statements to the rescue.

Note, I used `gunicorn -w 1 -t 1 wsgi:app` to ensure single worker & thread, as otherwise the console is spammed with `print` statements from multple sources.

Importing & loading order is the likely culprit. There's also an issue with the statement `load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))` in `configmodule.py`. it looks for the `.env` file in the directory `denise` and fails silently.

I've made a minimally reproducable example, see below.

### The fix is to either:

- do the `load_dotenv('.env')` in `wsgi.py` before importing anything from `denise`
- change the way you load inside `configmodule.py` to `load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '../.env'))`, but since you use the Application Factory Pattern structure I'm not sure if this is advisable though. This can lead to undesired behavior in the future.

### configmodule.py

```py
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values
from pprint import pprint


print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('configmodule')
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')


basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
try:
    with open(path.join(basedir, '.env')) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            print(line)
except:
    print('=========================== FILENOTFOUND')


class Config(object):
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('configmodule:Config')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    pprint(dotenv_values(path.join(basedir, '.env')))
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    pprint(environ)
    DEBUG=True
    SECRET_KEY=environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///site.db'
    ENV='development'
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = environ.get('EMAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER')
    MAIL_MAX_EMAILS = 5
    RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC')
    RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE')
```

### wsgi.py

```py
from os import environ
from denise import create_app
from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values


print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('WSGI')
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
load_dotenv('.env')
print(dotenv_values('.env'))
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
with open('.env') as infile:
    print(infile.readlines())
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(environ)
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I would suggest to modify `wsgi.py` to prevent future issues, as stated above, although this might violate PEP8 standards.

### The fixed wsgi.py

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.env')

from denise import create_app


app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

(writing from phone)

Have a look at your wsgi file:

1. first you import create_app, it goes to your `__init__` file
2. `__init__` file imports Config, which is not lazily initialized, but on import (i’d change this, but it’s not an issue)
3. in config file you take dirname of `__file__`, which is `denise`, then you join it with `.env`, while there is no env file in denise directory

Regarding running flask run to debug, I don’t use flask, but it may just not use wsgi file.